# setTextsize of textview as per scaling do in scalegesture in multitouchlistner

Tags: android, textview

I did scale,rotate,touch in one touchlistner. But there is one issue that i don't know how to change textsize of textview as per scaling. I tries many links but not working properly.

I want autoresize text in textview as per scalling.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**`SDP - a scalable size unit`**](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

> An android SDK that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This
>   size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers
>   with supporting multiple screens.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
}
```

**XML**

```
 <TextView

        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />
```

**Java**

```
 int textSize = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._12sdp);
 .setTextSize(textSize);
```